# Orbits of the permutation action of a subgroup on its cosets

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, representation-theory, characters

Consider a finite group $G$ and a subgroup $H \subseteq G$. There is a transitive group action of $G$ on the set of left cosets $gH$ by left multiplication, and the stabilizer of $gH$ is $gHg^{-1}$. Now, restrict this action to $H$. It is clearly no longer transitive, as $1H$ is a fixed point.

What are some natural conditions on $G$ and $H$ such that $H$ acts transitively on the set of non-identity cosets? The only (necessary but not obviously sufficient) condition I can come up with is that either $[G:H] = 2$, or the normalizer of $H$ is just equal to $H$. This is necessary since if $g$ normalizes $H$, then $HgH = gHg^{-1} gH = gH$, so if there are more than one non-identity cosets, $g$ must be in $H$.

My motivation is that I'm working through Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*, and exercise 7.2 asks me to determine when the permutation representation $\rho$ of $G$ given by its action on the left cosets satisfies $\rho = 1 \oplus \tau$ for $\tau$ irreducible.

Letting $\chi$ be the character of $\rho$ and $\psi$ the character of $\tau$, we have $$(\psi, \psi) = (\rho, \rho) - 2(\rho, 1) + 1$$

Since $\rho$ is a transitive permutation representation, $(\rho, 1) =1$, so $\tau$ is irreducible iff $(\rho, \rho) = 2$.

Since $\rho = \text{Ind}_H^G(1)$, Fronenius reciprocity gives 
$$(\rho, \rho) = (\rho, \text{Ind}_H^G(1)) = (\rho|_H, 1)$$

Since the restriction of $\rho$ to $H$ is still a permutation representation, $(\rho|_H, 1)$ is the number of orbits of this action under $H$.

Comment: I would descibe $gH$ as a left coset rather than a right coset. A group action in which  the point stabilizer $H$ acts transitively on the remaining points is called $2$-transitive or doubly transitive, and the image of the action (i.e. the induced  permutation group on the cosets) is called a $2$-transitive permutation group. There is a lot of literature on these groups. Using the classification of finite simple groups, the finite $2$-transitive groups have been completely classified.

Comment: ^changed to left. That terminology always confuses me... Are there any elementary properties of 2-transitive groups which might be interesting at this level?